# when i run a NiFi processor it no longer works again

Tags: regex, apache-nifi, processors

I'm new to NiFi, assume that I don't know anything. I have it installed locally and I try to make a flow that takes some files from an SFTP and passes them to an AzureDataLake. I use ListSFTP, FetchSFTP, and PutAzureDataLakeStorage. Then I'll want to put a ValidateCsv between the Fetch and the Put. But for now I have two problems.

1. The first is that whatever flow I create, I **run it once**, and if it works, **it doesn't work anymore**. **Even if I turn off the server** and everything. I have to re-create it from scratch to do the next test. I don't know why this could be, but **it really slows me down**.
2. The second, I want to **take only files** that respond to a specific **name format** (**TAL_dddd_dddd_dddddddd.0 being the d digits**). What I do is the List, and in the **Fetch, in its Remote File put** something like this **./upload/NOMBRE/${filename:matches('TAL_\d{4}*\d{4}*\d{8}.0')}**. But **it does not work**. **I was going to test with ./upload/NOMBRE/${'TAL_\d{4}*\d{4}*\d{8}.0'}**. But of course, problem 1 occurs and before redoing the entire flow I have come to ask.

I would appreciate the help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe you file name is not exactly matching, try replacing `matches` with `find`.

Comment: Regarding your first problem, the processor that executes only one time and doesn't work anymore is the ListSFTP? Did you tried clearing it's state? Processors that lists files from external filesystems saves the state of the last execution, so it would not duplicate when you execute the processor again. Regarding the File Name, you could do some tests with RouteOnAttribute and verify which files would match your RegEx, that way your tests would be more "visual". Here are the search expressions of NiFi https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#find

Comment: @KevinBarranco, you were right about the state.
While testing I discovered that it is as easy as leaving filtering for ListSFTP instead of FetchSFTP. By adding a regular expression to the File Filter Regex property of the ListSFTP (for example ^TAL_\d{4}_\d{4}_\d{8}\.0$), only the files that correspond to this name format are listed . Then, in the FetchSFTP, it is enough to put something like PATH/${filename} in its Remote File property to get the files.
If GetSFTP is used instead of List and Fetch, the filtering is done right there, as it also has the File Filter Regex property.